# React, component calling multiple times my back end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am relatively new to React and learning it. I am trying to get a new Post using `axios`. But when I hit the `'/getPost'` URL, the `GetPost` component is calling continuously the backend. Is this the expected behavior?

Below are the code snippets:

```js
// important imports
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Routes }
    from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Create from './component/Create';
import Edit from './component/Edit';
import GetPost from './component/GetPost';
import Home from './component/Home';

function App ()  {
  return (
  <div className='App'>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path ='' element= {<Home></Home>}> </Route>
        <Route path ='/edit' aelement= {<Edit/>}> </Route>
        <Route path='/create' element= {<Create/>}></Route>
        <Route path='/getPost' element= {<GetPost/>}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>

  </div>

  )
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const GetPost = () => {
    const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);

    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        .then(res => {

            console.log(res.data);
            setPerson(res.data);
        })

    return (
        person.map(p =>
            <div>
                {p.id}
            </div>
        )
    )

}
export default GetPost;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `axios` call inside `GetPost`. It executes when the components get mounted and set the state by calling `setPerson(res.data)`, which will trigger a re-render, then the `axios` part gets re-executed, and that will be forever.

To avoid this issue, you would wanna use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook from React, something like so:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const GetPost = () => {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      setPerson(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return person.map((p) => <div>{p.id}</div>);
};
export default GetPost;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about fetching data in useEffect like below?

```
useEffect(() => {
   const load = async () => {
     const res = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
     console.log(res.data);
     setPerson(res.data);
   }

   load();
}, []);
```

I guess the reason GetPost component keeps being called is that you update state in the component which causes re-render the component like explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/re-rendering-components-in-reactjs/#:%7E:text=React%20components%20automatically%20re%2Drender,in%20their%20state%20or%20props.&text=A%20simple%20update%20of%20the,to%20be%20re%2Drendered%20automatically.).

Answer (score 0):

Make your API call in UseEffect to resolve this-

```
useEffect(()=>{
      axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            setPerson(res.data);
      })
},[])
```

Also, you make these following changes in your App.js-

```
<div className='App'>
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path ='/' element= {<Home/>}> </Route>
    <Route exact path ='/edit' element= {<Edit/>}> </Route>
    <Route exact path='/create' element= {<Create/>}></Route>
    <Route exact path='/getPost' element= {<GetPost/>}></Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```